# Should there be a distance between the terminator of a protein with the promoter of another one?

Tags: promotor

I want to do an overlap PCR to get the desired gene product I want. Can I put the promoter of the second protein just after the terminator of the first protein, or should there be some distance between them filled with random bases?!